# How use custom image size + ACF + background image

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, images

How to get the URL from an image with custom image size to use as a background-image from AFC?

Register size in functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180 ); // Soft Crop
```

Display image with custom size (named: customsize) on page with ACF:

```
<?php $image = get_field('image_field'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['customsize']; ?> />
```

But how to display image as background image with ACF?:

```
<?php $image = get_field('image_field'); ?>             
<div style="background-image: url(<?php $image['url'] ?>)" /></div>
```

Comment: what is the HTML output when you run your last snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this code...

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['customsize']; ?> />
```

is missing the end quote, it should be...

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['customsize']; ?>" />
```

You can use that same php to output the URL for the background size.

```
<div style="height: 300px; width: 300px; background-image: url(<?php echo $company_logo['sizes']['customsize']; ?>)" /></div>
```

Tested and works.